# More efficient algorithm for filling in correlation matrix

Tags: algorithm, performance, correlation

I'm looking at something where a series of factors are partitioned in various different ways and then each combination has a correlation. Ultimately this would then result in the total for each top level partition being given by vᵀ**ρ**v.

I know that this could be done in a naive way of comparing each entry of the factors to the others with a higher index and then filling in from there, but this would be a loop within a loop.

What I'm wondering is if there is a more efficient way of doing this, potentially only requiring a single loop through? I'd then look at applying a Euler allocation so the quicker the underlying is the more efficient the overall piece would be.

Comment: Whether you use a single loop or a nested loop, there are n^2 entries that need to be generated to construct the correlation matrix (or n*(n+1)/2 if you represent it in triangular form, which is still O(n^2)). Unless you have some way to make that go away, the best you can do is fiddle with the constants in O(n^2).

Comment: I guess if you want to be pedantic, it's n*(n-1)/2 for correlation, since the diagonal is all 1's and thus doesn't need to be calculated or stored. That's still O(n^2) though.

Comment: @pjs so there’s no way to reduce the overall time complexity of the problem?

Comment: If you mean big-O complexity, not that I can see. As I mentioned, you can perhaps affect the actual run time via the constants.

Comment: Yeah big-O complexity. When you say fiddle with the constants, what do you mean there?

Comment: For example, you might get a small speed up using bit shifting rather than division by powers of 2, depending on the language and the compiler’s optimizing capabilities. Maybe that makes the actual run time 7n^2 rather than 8n^2 if you fit the timings in a regression model. Both are O(n^2), but the latter yields faster actual run times due to the smaller multiplicative constant. However, trading off readability or maintainability is often not worth it unless benchmarks show that particular calculation to be a bottleneck.